# Adding 2 sine waves in buffer creates noise

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, signal-processing

When I am adding a sine wave of 10 kHz to another of 12 kHz and output them together from the iPhone speaker I can hear other lower frequencies which should not be there.

In order to do this, I create a sine wave and fill the buffer with samples, then add the samples of another sine wave to the buffer.

Each of these individual sine waves is working correctly separately, but when they are combined I can hear distortion that wasn't there before.

This is my callback code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <inNumberFrames; i++)
{

    buffer[i] = buffer[i]+ sin(theta12_8) * myInstance->amplitude;
    theta12_8 += 2.0 * M_PI * 12800  / (myInstance->sampleRate); 
    if (theta12_8 > 2.0 * M_PI)
    {
        theta12_8 -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i <inNumberFrames; i++)
{

    buffer[i] = buffer[i]+ sin(theta10) * myInstance->amplitude;
    theta10 += 2.0 * M_PI * 10000  / (myInstance->sampleRate);;
    if (theta10 > 2.0 * M_PI)
    {
        theta10 -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
}
```

Comment: What lower frequency do you think should not be there?  You're gonna get a 2KHz component and a 22KHz component.

Comment: @HotLicks Why should there be these components? Even if you're thinking of the transformation of sum into product for trigonometric functions, we're not talking about this at all.

Comment: First check that it works properly with only one frequency. Then add both frequency, but divide both amplitudes by 2. You might reach some threshold that adds distortion and hence adds lower frequency harmonics (and these would be the components Hot Licks is talking about, well, especially the lower frequency one).

Comment: @HotLicks how did you calculate that ? i can say that frequency above 10 i can barely hear,than when they are together i hear a strong noise, i g uess its frequencies of about 2-7khz or something

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf i wrote that i have checked that already and they are working great separate . i will reduce amp thanks a lot.

Comment: great ! i did amp=0.5 and its gone !!! thanks a lot both of you !

Comment: @Rant -- When you "sum" sine waves through a system with any sort of nonlinearity you get "sum" and "difference" frequencies.  A basic principle of radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your sine wave to be at amplitude 1, thats ok.
If you add 2 sine waves together, so the max amplitude of the new one can be 2, and thats wrong number,and create distortions and harmonics .

I have set the amplitude to be 0.5 on each one of them,so the max is 1, and it solve the problem.